# C# Join multiple collections into one

Tags: c#, linq

i have problem with joining multiple collections into one
-> I need collections with data from many sensors connect into one to have for each time values from all sensors in output file, f.e. if one sensor have no data, it will fill file with 0
Please help me, I am desperate

```
public class MeasuredData
{
    public DateTime Time { get; }
    public double Value { get; }        

    public MeasuredData(DateTime time, double value)
    {
        Time = time;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The multiple collections are of the same type? Like List<MeasuredData>?

Comment: Yes, all collection are List<MeasuredData> and I need to export file where for every Time from all MeasuredData collection will be it's Value or "0" if not exist

Comment: If you have multiple collections the you can have something like `var newColl = new List<MeasuredData>(); newColl.AddRange(coll1); newColl.AddRange(coll2); ... And so on.. `

Comment: I need to export that then like data table in format -> Time1 | Sensor 1 Value | Sensor2 value | Sensor3 value

Comment: To be able to combine the collections you need a time stamp on each collection so the times of all the data is the same which you have.  
Because every measurement is occurring exactly at the same time you need to round the time to the nearest second (or finer time) to be able to join

Comment: What do mean by "has no data"? do you mean the collection is empty (Count = 0)?
and what do you mean "it will fill file with 0", do you mean assigning `Value` a value of 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple variables containing `List<MeasuredData>`, one for each sensor, you can group them in an array and then query them.

First, you need an extension method to round the `DateTime`s per @jdweng if you aren't already canonicalizing them as you acquire them.

```
public static DateTime Round(this DateTime dt, TimeSpan rnd) {
    if (rnd == TimeSpan.Zero)
        return dt;
    else {
        var ansTicks = dt.Ticks + Math.Sign(dt.Ticks) * rnd.Ticks / 2;
        return new DateTime(ansTicks - ansTicks % rnd.Ticks);
    }
}
```

Now you can create an array of the sensor reading `List`s:

```
var sensorData = new[] { sensor0, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3 };
```

Then you can extract all the rounded times to create the left hand side of the table:

```
var roundTo = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
var times = sensorData.SelectMany(sdl => sdl.Select(md => md.Time.Round(roundTo)))
                      .Distinct()
                      .Select(t => new { Time = t, Measurements = Enumerable.Empty<MeasuredData>() });
```

Then you can join each sensor to the table:

```
foreach (var oneSensorData in sensorData)
    times = times.GroupJoin(oneSensorData, t => t.Time, md => md.Time.Round(roundTo),
        (t, mdj) => new { t.Time, Measurements = t.Measurements.Concat(mdj) });
```

Finally, you can convert each row to the time and a `List` of measurements ordered by time:

```
var ans = times.Select(tm => new { tm.Time, Measurements = tm.Measurements.ToList() })
               .OrderBy(tm => tm.Time);
```

If you wanted to flatten the `List` of measurements out to fields in the answer, you would need to do that manually with another `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something to join on, you can use [Enumerable.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = collection1.Join(collection2,
/* whatever your join is */   x => x.id,
                              y => y.id,
                              (a, b) => new {x = a, y = b}

foreach(var obj in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{obj.x.id}, {obj.y.id}")
}
```

This prints the id's of the two objects, but they could access anything. The link is probably more helpful, but you didn't give us much info